# Unpack cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a `100x1` cell array, whose each element is an `1x2` cell array.

How may I unpack it into a `100x2` cell array *elegantly*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `A` as the input cell array -

```
out = vertcat(A{:})
```

or -

```
out  = reshape([A{:}],2,[]).'
```

Comment: One year later, I met the same issue. Your answer saved me again. Thanks!